# Algorithm to get a range of discontinuous values

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am trying to draw a "broken" ellipse via:

```
PointF p; 
List<IntPoint> list;
int res = 1000;
for(int i = 0; i < res; ++i)
{
    if(i <= 250) // do nothing
    else
    {
        p.X = h + a * Math.Cos(i/res * Math.PI * 2);
        p.Y = k + b * Math.Sin(i/res * Math.PI * 2);
        list.Add(p);
    }  
}
```

This code will cut the first 1/4 of the ellipse off and store the valid points in `list`. In this case it is easy to say that the range of valid angle lies from 90 to 360 degrees.

However what if I want to have an ellipse like this (assuming the cutting off point is known):
[image]

Now that the angle is not a continuous value (since valid angle is from about 100-360 degrees & 0-70 degrees), is there an algorithm to quantify the range of valid angles? If so, what should the data structure look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angles wrap. so you can treat (100, 360) + (0,70) as (100,360)+(360,430), i.e. it is simply (100,430).

```
    int startAngle = 100;
    int endAngle = 430;
    PointF p; 
    List<IntPoint> list;
    int res = 1000;
    for(int i = startAngle*res/360; i <= endAngle*res/360; ++i)
    {
        p.X = h + a * Math.Cos(i/res * Math.PI * 2);
        p.Y = k + b * Math.Sin(i/res * Math.PI * 2);
        list.Add(p);
    }
```

I've left the code close to yours, but unless there is a specific reason, you might want to use floating point rather than `int`.